# Issue in allocating memory for resizing stack

Tags: c++, oop, memory-management, constructor, stack

I have tried and tried to figure the mistake in my code , but I still can't find it.I have a Stack class Album, which i want to resize, and think i did it right.For some reason however most of the times the program crashes and maybe one in 10 works fine and I have no idea why.If you could point the mistake that would be great. So here is the code:

---

```
const Song Song::null_song;//static from Song class

class Album
{
    Song* songs;
    char* name;
    int top;
    int capacity;
    bool full () const;
    void resize ();

public:
    ...
}
```

---

And here are the functions, somewhere in them is the culprit.The problem happens when I try to push more items in Album then the predefined INIT_CAPACITY=4.I think it should work, but it doesn't, so the problem must be allocating the new memory.

---

```
const int INIT_CAPACITY=4;

std::ostream& operator<<(std::ostream& os, Album& p)
{
    os<<"Name of Album:"<<p.name<<std::endl;
    for(int i=0;i<=p.top;i++)
        os<<p.songs[i]<<std::endl;
}

Album::Album(const char* p)
{
    int len1=strlen(p);
    name=new char [len1+1];
    strcpy(name,p);
    top=-1;
    songs = new Song[INIT_CAPACITY];
    capacity = INIT_CAPACITY;
}

Song Album::pop()
{
    if (empty())
        return Song::null_song;
    return songs[top--];
}

Song Album::last() const
{
    if (empty())
        return Song::null_song;
    return songs[top];
}

bool Album::push(Song x)
{
    if (full())
        resize();
    songs[++top] = x;
    return true;
}

void Album::resize()
{
    capacity *= 2;
    Song* newsongs = new Song[capacity];
    for(int i = 0; i < capacity / 2; i++)
        newsongs[i] = songs[i];
    delete[] songs;
    songs = newsongs;
}

bool Album::empty() const
{
    return top == -1;
}

bool Album::full() const
{
    return top == capacity-1;
}

Album::Album()
{
    top=-1;
    songs = new Song[INIT_CAPACITY];
    capacity = INIT_CAPACITY;

    name=new char [1];
    name[0]='\0';
}

Album::~Album()
{
    delete [] songs;
    delete [] name;
}
```

Comment: Hi.  Asking people to spot errors in your code is not especially productive. You should use the debugger (or add print statements) to isolate the problem, by tracing the progress of your program, and comparing it to what you expect to happen. As soon as the two diverge, then you've found your problem. (And then if necessary, you should construct a [minimal test-case](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).)

Comment: use std::string and std::vector, stop using new and delete and your problems will go away

Comment: @OliCharlesworth well I tried but as you can see I still haven't become good in programing. As i wrote the problem appears when I tried to have more items than are aloud in INIT_CAPACITY. The problem is I think I have a problem in the logic, which is harder to find.

Comment: if you think the class implementation of `Song` isn't relevant, think again; it is. Ex: `new Song[INIT_CAPACITY]` will fire the default constructor for `Song` exactly `INIT_CAPACITY` times. What is *in* that constructor is relevant. The loop that does `newsongs[i] = songs[i]` fires assignment operators for `Song`. That assignment operator is relevant. `delete [] songs;` fires the N destructors. What is in *that* is relevant. Passing `(Song song)` as a value-parameter fires the `Song` copy constructor. Etc... See [Rule of Three](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rule_of_three_(C%2B%2B_programming))

Comment: i think you should add some checks on the value of 'top'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `Song` also uses `char*` where it should use `std::string`.

It deletes this pointer in the destructor, but you haven't defined an assignment operator or copy constructor.

This makes all `Song`s contain invalid pointers once you have resized an `Album`.

Comment: if you mean char* name, that's the name of the album and don't know how that affects the pointers to Song. Btw Song is consisted of char* title and char* author , if you think changing them to string I could try it , but don't think that would help.

Comment: @user3144334 I wrote `Song` because I meant `Song`, and your `title` and `author` pointers are exactly as I suspected.

Comment: Hmmm, I changed every char* to string and now it doesn't crash. But still it won't print after I go above INIT_CAPACITY :(

Comment: don't worry I fixed it, it seem that for the Song = operator i forgot to return Song& instead i wrote Song. Guess that  in {newsongs[i] = songs[i];
    delete[] songs;
    songs = newsongs;} was the problem